# Find height of a div

Tags: css, html, height

I got a small problem I can't find the height of my div, i get the data out of a Mysql database so it's just a bunch of text. but de height of container doesn't change so the background is only on the first part of the page.

I thought about using jQuery or something to find the height of the div and change my css to that.

This is the div I'm talking about

```
<div id="artistright">
<h2>Biografie</h2>
<br />
<?php echo $data['biografie']; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you just have `height: auto;` on the container?

Comment: can you provide sample html/css of the container?

Comment: i believe that you have css related issues, maybe with floating or some static heights. can you provide css of `id="artistright"` and `$data['biografie']` generated elements. Also is the website live? That would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular height

```
$('#id').height();
```

Height including margins

```
$('#id').outerHeight(true);
```

As long as the container is kept stock (`height:auto`), it should expand as needed. It's possible you're using floats and not clearing them (`clear:both`).

**Update:**
It looks like it is indeed a float issue. Floats must be properly cleared when you are through with them. You can add this:

`<div style="clear:both"></div>` right before the closing `<div>` of the section.

OR (as long as it doesn't mess up your layout)

Simply add `clear:both` as the last style in  `#artistsright`.

Comment: But how do i get this to a PHP variable?

Comment: Didn't see anything about in question.. if you're bringing in content from a database it should depend on the container it's in and the CSS governing it. Default is set to `height:auto`, so it should stretch unless there's a rule stated for it.

Comment: Using Firefox or Chrome inspection tool, you can select to see if there's CSS controlling it.

Comment: the height of my container is set to auto

Comment: Hmm.. not really enough code to see the issue. Something is affecting the height if it isn't expanding correctly, are you using floats?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4nAh7fvy
http://pastebin.com/1aP3gCBD

here is the code of my css and my page. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, consider reading up on PDO. It's more secure than MySQL (depreciated) and easier to use once you get the hang of it.

Comment: And i'm trying to do that in my spare time!